# iOS- sharekit - settings facebook

Tags: ios, settings, sharekit

I have a sharekit implementation where everything works fine, but if there is no account set for facebook, upon pressing the settings button, the actionsheet is just dismissed and the user is returned to the app, not to the settings page in system prefs.

How do I get the settings button to send the user to the settings page?

the code i use to init the action sheet:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"test"];


SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the action sheet
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but I'm lost, what exactly is the question here? Is this a statement or you actually need help with something?

Comment: oh sorry. just edited the question to include a question

Comment: Can you please post the code you have issues with? That way we all can try to contribute and offer help.

Comment: done. i mean there isnt much code really

Comment: You probably need an if statement to push the user to the view that you want or to the another view if there is no password or connection. This may already be obvious to you, but I'm away from Mac and have no way of posting a example code for you. Hopefully one of the guys will answer that for you before I get back to my Mac.

Comment: oh ok thx. i decided not to use sharekit

Comment: Cool I'm glad someone did help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known, unresolved issue](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/376) with ShareKit.  You could submit a pull request to fix it, or work around it by checking [SLComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205):

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    // show ShareKit
} else {
    // tell them to get Facebook
}
```

before displaying ShareKit.  Of course, that would make it so users without Facebook (like Twitter-only folks) couldn't use ShareKit.  On the other hand, you could switch over to Apple's Share Sheets, or write your own, but those also have their disadvantages.  Kind of a catch-22.